# Как принудительно запустить приложение через терминал

Tags: macos, shell

Есть приложение написанное на моно. Копирую exe-файл в Unix систему (OSX). Для его запуска мне приходится писать в консоли терминала `mono DemoApp.exe`. Я хочу чтобы все exe приложение запускались с данным префиксом `mono имя_приложения`. Как глобально задать ассоциацию запуска приложений?

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/#registering-exe-as-non-native-binaries-linux-only

Comment: поправил. Нужно было в MacOS сделать

Answer (score 1):

Мне на ум приходит только создать `alias` для команды запуска приложения. Например:

```
$ alias DemoApp="mono DemoApp.exe"
```

И запуск соответственно:

```
$ DemoApp
```

Comment: ну так все равно надо запуск из консоли делать)? А

Comment: Так заголовок вашего вопроса в этом же